# if-with-initializer in structured binding declaration example ill formed?

Tags: c++, c++17

I was reading through the [Structured binding declaration on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

I thought I was doing well understanding the examples until I reached the last example at the bottom.

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::set<std::string> myset;
    
    if (auto [iter, success] = myset.insert("Hello"); success) 
        std::cout << "insert is successful. The value is " << 
        std::quoted(*iter) << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "The value " << std::quoted(*iter) << " already 
        exists in the set\n";
}
```

At first glance it looked all right, but the more I looked at it the less I understood the if clause.

At the top are the possible forms listed as:

> attr(optional) cv-auto ref-operator(optional) [ identifier-list ] = expression ;   (1)
>
> attr(optional) cv-auto ref-operator(optional) [ identifier-list ] { expression } ; (2)
>
> attr(optional) cv-auto ref-operator(optional) [ identifier-list ] ( expression ) ; (3)

To me it looks like to be of deduction type (1). But it kind of makes no sense to me cause of

> expression    -   an expression that does not have the comma operator at the top level (grammatically, an assignment-expression), and has either array or non-union class type. If expression refers to any of the names from identifier-list, the declaration is ill-formed.

which says that the declaration is ill formed if the expression is in the identifier list. So this looks to me that success isn't part of expression. If this would be the case then

```
auto [iter, success] = myset.insert("Hello");
```

would only assign the inserted `"Hello"` to `iter` and `success` would be what?!? The other way around it would violate the expression part. But it clearly compiles and runs so I must be missing something

Comment: I think, the question should be rephrased - it is not about structured binding, it is actually about new `if`-with-initializer syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> which says that the declaration is ill formed if the expression is in the identifier list

It doesn't say that.  It says that if *expression* uses any of the names in the *identifier-list* it is ill-formed.  `myset.insert("Hello")` doesn't do that so it is okay.

`std::set::insert` returns a `std::pair<std::set::iterator, bool>` where the `std::set::iterator` marks the elements position and the `bool` indicates if it was inserted or not.  So `auto [iter, success] = myset.insert("Hello")` captures that pair and sets `iter` to the `std::set::iterator` and `success` to the `bool`.

Comment: that would make sense, but why is the second part of pair deduced to bool? because it matches the identifier success from the identifier-list?

Comment: @aldr The second part isn't deduced to a bool.  The `insert` function returns a `std::pair<std::set::iterator, bool>`.  It is that return type that the structured binding deduces from, and binds it's variables to.  A literal translation of `if (auto [iter, success] = myset.insert("Hello"); success) ` is: execute `myset.insert("Hello")` and from the pair that it returns store the iterator part in `iter` and the bool part in `success`.  Then if success is `true` execute the true part of the if statement.

Comment: @aldr No worries.  Glad to help.  C++ can be a *little* difficult ;)

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you are getting confused by structured binding and if with initializer, but the simple way to look at it is to decompose them.

```
if (auto [a, b] = foo(); b)
```

Consists of two parts = first is initializer (`auto [a, b] = foo()`) and second (b) is condition. It is exactly equivalent to

```
{
auto [a, b] = foo(); 
if (b)
}
```

In the example above, `a` and `b` would be deduced to whatever return type of `foo` mandates, having nothing to do with `if` condition below that.